# I made a temperature controller - the PID works but the heater still doesn't work

Tags: temperature, pid-controller, heater

The setpoint doesn't affect the output voltage to heater.

How can I fix my circuit so current goes through to the heater?

[image: schematic circuit]

Comment: Report all Vouts and don’t let them saturate. Your Ki is too high , too fast for thermal lag

Comment: The 741 needs a bipolar supply - you need a -12V supply as well as +12V.

Comment: Yes i use the bipolar supply , and the output from pid to mosfet is 12 Volt for higher setpoint , the problem is from mosfet to the heater

Comment: looks like you are giving sensor output from TMP36 gain of 1000x?? why? // also, very minor note, the 1nF on the differentiator was drawn with resistor symbol

Comment: I use 1000 gain because sensor output is very small

Comment: are you sure? what is the voltage produced by the sensor at room temperature? what will happen if you multiply it by 1000?

Comment: When around 25 C , the voltage to the opamp is around      
 7 mV , if not connected to opamp , it would be normal at 0.7 V

Comment: @谢RenS Doesn't the TMP36 datasheet say that the maximum current compliance is \$50\:\mu\text{A}\$? What do you imagine will happen between its output and the virtual ground through the \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$? I'd be looking for a much higher input impedance design for your first 741 opamp stage.

Comment: @谢RenS Also, what do you want for the sensor's cutoff frequency?